# Why is this double negative query different from a positive query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I make two queries that should select the same group of people,  they have different results. The logic is the same, but the numbers are different.

Here is my model: Person class with age:integer name:string pet:string

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  PET_TYPES = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'fish']
  validates :pet, inclusion: { in: PET_TYPES }, allow_nil: true
  validates :age, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
end
```

I've filled the database with people having each type of pet (including nil) either below age 21 or above age 21 in my seed file:

```
Person.all.destroy_all
Person::PET_TYPES.each do |pet|
    10.times do |n|
        Person.create!(name: "Person-young-#{pet}-#{n}", pet: pet, age: (1..20).to_a.sample)
    end
    10.times do |n|
        Person.create!(name: "Person-old-#{pet}-#{n}", pet: pet, age: (21..80).to_a.sample)
    end
end
10.times do |n|
    Person.create!(name: "Person-young-no-pet-#{n}", pet: nil, age: (1..20).to_a.sample)
end
10.times do |n|
    Person.create!(name: "Person-old-no-pet-#{n}", pet: nil, age: (21..80).to_a.sample)
end
```

I executed the following two queries, which should select the same group of people. But I get different numbers.

```
Person.count
#>>   (1.0ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people"
#=> 100
Person.where.not(id: Person.where.not('age > ? AND pet = ?', 21, 'dog')).count
#>>   (1.7ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "people"."id" FROM "people" WHERE NOT (age > 21 AND pet = 'dog'))
#=> 20
Person.where('age > ? AND pet = ?', 21, 'dog').count
#>>   (1.0ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people" WHERE (age > 21 AND pet = 'dog')
#=> 10
```

Shouldn't these two statements return the same number?

Comment: are you sure you're getting the same results ?, execute both queries in your posgresql console. Remove the count first, and select `age` and `pet` for both queries and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL, `null` is not equal (`=`) to anything —- not even to another `null`. Moreover, this is a common example of [**Three-valued logic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). When you compare `null` with anything else, it's *neither true nor false*; it's `UNKNOWN`.

The fundamental "problem" is (as discussed in more depth [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19262)) that `where.not(x: true)` is `WHERE x != true`; it is *not* the negative form of `WHERE x == true`.

Let's break down your problem to a **Minimal**, Complete, Verifiable Example:

```
Person.count
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people"
=> 100
Person.where(pet: 'dog').count
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people" WHERE "people"."pet" = 'dog'
=> 20
Person.where.not(pet: 'dog').count
   (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people" WHERE "people"."pet" != 'dog'
=> 60
Person.where.not(pet: 'dog').pluck(:pet).uniq
=> ["cat", "bird", "fish"]
```

As you can see, the people with a `null` pet are missing from both results.

---

So to summarise, your attempt to double-negate the query actually results in a different result set due to the three-valued logic.

`Person.where.not('age > ? AND pet = ?', 21, 'dog')` includes everyone except old people *with a dog* **and** old people **with no pet**.

Comment: On a separate, less important, note: You have an off-by-1 error. You're creating "old" people in the age range `21-80` but then querying people aged `> 21`. That should, instead, be a query for people aged `> 20`.